# No such input format: MJPEG

Tags: usb, ffmpeg, webcam, v4l2

I want to convert my camera pixels format from YUYV to MJPEG. I tried to use `v4l-utils` but when i used this commend in terminal:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -pixel_format MJPEG -i /dev/video0
```

but when I get this:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1aa4380] No such input format: MJPEG.
/dev/video0: Invalid argument
```

So what's the wrong, and what should I do here to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-pixel_format` use `-vcodec` like below:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -vcodec MJPEG -i /dev/video0
```

Comment: i get this error Unknown decoder 'MJPEG'

Comment: try this to get more information:`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -list_options true -i /dev/video0`

Comment: i get this error 
Unrecognized option 'list_options'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Comment: Sorry, try `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -list_formats 1 -i /dev/video0` to list the available formats.  Also, your video camera might not support MJPEG, have you verified this?

Comment: that's are my output http://pastebin.com/EWp34fbF how to verified my camera ?

Comment: that's what i get when i use this command ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0  http://pastebin.com/vPp7J5p5

Comment: and when i used that i get ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -list_formats all 
http://pastebin.com/UQ9GPw4J

Comment: @shar Then that confirms it: your camera only provides "raw" output, so you can't select mjpeg.

Comment: there are anyway to change it and what that should be to able to select mjpeg ?

Comment: and what format should i use ?

Comment: I think the solution is getting a different webcam that supports MJPEG output.

Comment: @Matt how i know if that allow mjpeg output ?